# Mysql Multiple queries to calculate values for month

Tags: php, mysql

first of all i want to extract dates of the relevant month from the database.for that i have used following query and i had generated the following output.

code

```
SELECT DISTINCT date as tot FROM attendance WHERE date LIKE '%2016-06%'
```

output

[image]

then i need to get the present `employees` for that dates from the database.but when i try that, it gives me total for one date only.how can i over come this.Here is my code.

```
SELECT DISTINCT date as days, COUNT(DISTINCT employee_id) as tot FROM attendance WHERE in_time != '' AND out_time != '' AND date LIKE '%2016-06%'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `group by`.  `mysql` just returns an arbitrary value when you omit fields from the `select` list that are not included in `aggregate` functions.  Then you can remove `distinct`:

```
SELECT date as days, COUNT(DISTINCT employee_id) as tot 
FROM attendance 
WHERE in_time != '' AND out_time != '' AND date LIKE '%2016-06%'
GROUP BY date
```

---

Per comment, what data type is your `date` field?  Assuming it's a date, you could remove `like` and use `year` and `month`:

```
AND Month(date) = 6 AND Year(date) = 2016
```

Comment: why he is using LIKE why not MONTH() and YEAR()